# Construct the src in a javascript tag from node fields

Tags: nodes, javascript

I have a drupal 7 instance where I would like to create nodes that call reports from a separate site using javascript.

Currently I construct the HTML tags myself which look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://URL.goes.here/JsAPI?reportUUID=[REPORTID]&amp;yfFiltera5d74aca-4396-41c2-9376-d68fd57de81a=[FILTERVALUE]&display=[DISPLAY]&canChangeDisplay=[CANCHANGEVALUE]&showPageLinks=[SHOWPAGESVALUE]&showInfo=[SHOWINFOVALUE]&showFilters=[SHOWFILTERSVALUE]&showSections=[SHOWSECTIONSVALUE]"></script>
```

Note that there are a bunch of parameters in the url shown in square brackets: [VALUE]

What I want to do is have a node creation interface for admin users that allows them to set all of the parameter values and constructs that URL, then constructs a string using those parameters and uses it as the node's output when viewed.

I haven't been able to find any kind of module for this, maybe I am describing it wrong - or maybe it's a very rare use-case.  Any ideas would be wonderful, even if it's 'hire a developer, this has never been done before'.

Comment: Well there's definitely no module for it. Does it need to be in the head tag?

Comment: Nope, just in the body (with filters turned off) as I want to be an integral part of the page.  A friend has offered to help, I may use this as a project to learn how to make modules, though I don't know how often it would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a *node.tpl.php* file in your theme or to be specific to one content type.

Duplicate the default node.tpl.php file found in */modules/node/* and rename it to *node-NODETYPE.tpl.php* NODETYPE being the machine name of the node which you can find at *structure -> content types*, in the CMS.

Install the devel module and enable it, then do a `dpm($node);` in your copied *node.tpl.php* file to get the variables you need. Of course you would need to have a custom theme so it doesn't get overridden on an update.

To do this in a module you'd need be somewhat familiar with hooks.

And since the *dpm* is called after the output is rendered you need to reload the page twice.
Don't forget to clear cache after you add in the *node.tpl.php* to your theme.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful!  I can't upvote yet, but I will hold off 'accepting' the answer until I've seen it work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And thanks Darvenen. Just add a comment if you need some more help but really this is a well documented process "getting node values in node.tpl.php"

Comment: I'm halfway there - I only stopped because my work day ended =)
So far the advice has been very sound.